# Same RequestMap table for all/many Apps

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

Can a Spring Security `RequestMaps` database table be *grails application specific*?

e.g.,
instead of having a rule like:

```
'/protectedcontroller/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
```

which only one grails app could use, I want to have all my rules for allmy grails app in one table...rules would then look like:

```
'/grailsapp1/protectedcontroller/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
'/grailsapp1/protectedcontroller/js/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],

'/grailsapp2/protectedcontroller/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'],
'/grailsapp2/unprotectedcontroller/**': ['IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY'],
```

etc.
?

I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work.

Reason I am asking is, I want to store all my different apps `RequestMaps` in **ONE** table in the `database`.

Comment: Bump...anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This blog shows how you would do that:

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/

You should have a look at "Dynamic request maps" in the blog. You will need to add a couple lines to `Config.groovy`, and then you can start creating `Requestmaps`:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType
...
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
```

Comment: Yes, I am using that already...but I have several Grails apps that need to share the same table RequestMaps...how can I make separate rules for them? I changed my question above to make it more clear what I need...